# GraphQL: how to have it return a flexible, dynamic array, depending on what the marketeer filled in?

Tags: graphql

The potential problem is as follows:

GraphQL expects you to specify exactly which fields you want it to return. So let's say we have a product like this:

```
productId
title
slug
selectedOptions.[someAttributeId].defaultValue
selectedOptions.[someAttributeId].name
selectedOptions.[someAttributeId].description
selectedOptions.[someOtherAttributeId].defaultValue
selectedOptions.[someOtherAttributeId].name
selectedOptions.[someOtherAttributeId].description
selectedOptions.[...etc].defaultValue
selectedOptions.[...etc].name
selectedOptions.[...etc].description
...etc
```

I removed the JSON syntax for easier reading. Point is: how many attributes there are and which attributes there are differs per product.

Can I tell GraphQL to just return the field 'selectedOptions' and everything it contains? Or do I need some complex work-around to retrieve the attribute IDs and work that into my query?

Comment: This has been asked and answered several times before. For example, see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45842544/graphql-objecttype-with-dynamic-fields-based-on-arguments) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46944891/dynamic-field-in-graphql-object-type). The bottom line is unless you're ok with changing the structure into an array, you'll need to utilize a JSON scalar or some other custom scalar. Either way, let's close this question as a duplicate.